# Ubuntu server ports refuse connection occasionally

Tags: networking, server, connection

### Background

I have Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (server) running multiple services, including the usual ssh, samba and then quite a few other things, including home automation, Nextcloud, etc. It serves up my entire digital life, and it did so quite well until a few months ago. I should add that the machine itself has a Xeon CPU, 12GB of ECC RAM and a ZFS filesystem running a mirrored pool. All of this hardware has been faultless, to my knowledge. I also try to keep Ubuntu up-to-date, so it is patched with whatever is the latest from the repo.

### Problem

Recently, I have noticed that I get odd connection drops for short periods. Sometimes I noticed that a SSH connection stops working. Other times I notice that I can't access the Samba file share, or maybe Nextcloud refuses a connection. Different things. As soon as it happens, I ping the machine and without fail the ping works fine, but I cannot connect to **anything**.

### Fault finding

Realising that the port connections seem to the problem, I started logging the output from:

```sh
    nc -v -w 5 -z 192.168.1.68 22
```

which produces:

```
Tue Mar 23 08:18:00 GMT 2021  - Connection to 192.168.1.68 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
Tue Mar 23 08:18:05 GMT 2021  - nc: connect to 192.168.1.68 port 22 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Tue Mar 23 08:18:10 GMT 2021  - nc: connect to 192.168.1.68 port 22 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
<---snip--->
Tue Mar 23 08:18:41 GMT 2021  - nc: connect to 192.168.1.68 port 22 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Tue Mar 23 08:18:46 GMT 2021  - nc: connect to 192.168.1.68 port 22 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Tue Mar 23 08:18:51 GMT 2021  - Connection to 192.168.1.68 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
Tue Mar 23 08:18:56 GMT 2021  - Connection to 192.168.1.68 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

Notice that the duration of the connection problem is slightly less than a minute. I have peered over logs in `/var/log`, `/var/snap/*/log`, `journalctl`, even router logs; tried to shutdown the various services, LXC instances, snap services, anything I could do without. I cannot see any correlation with an event, or indication that something is wrong. For example, I cannot see daemons crashing, logging errors, an increase in system load, or any particular service running at (or just before) a connection drop occurs.

I have also run a similar `nc` command from the server to a client and in that log **I can see that the outbound connections have a similar problem**, albeit for shorter periods.

### Question to the community

What else can I do to diagnose this problem? Could it be hardware, e.g.: Network interface (which is embedded on the Motherboard), Router, cabling. If so, how would I check? And if not hardware, then this leaves the software but where to start?

Comment: Read `man journalctl `, and use the `--since` and `--until` switches to inspect the logs around those times.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator. Yes, I have done that, and as I said, there was nothing in there that leaps out as a problem. That said, there is obviously a lot being logged in the journal. I'm not a networking expert, or any kind of IT expert to be fair. What I am hoping for is the next step, after merely looking at all the logs. Is there a lower-level where I can go take a look?

Comment: Try `sudo journalctl ...`. Regular users don't have access to all the logs.

Comment: @waltinator yes, I've done that too. Is it possible that a process can block IO in such a way that nothing can get to the network interface, and would there be a warning in a log if this were possible?

Comment: Read `man top`. Use `top` in batch (`-b`) mode to grab repeated (`-n` and -d` options) snapshots of the system state. System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. Especially since you have 12GB RAM.

Comment: I have not actually done this, but I did look into it... I use `htop` generally, and looked at `ps` for logging. Did not think to use `top`, so will give that a try now. I did log the system load via `cat /proc/loadavg` but since the connection issue was so short, it did not show much: Load average is reported for 1m, 5m and 15m intervals.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18. Maybe 18.04?

Comment: I'm no expert in this, but when I last experienced "weird connection losses" before, I focussed my search on the hardware.  So swap in/out cables, router, computer...whatever I could think of.  I guess it could be either hardware or software, but I guess it's easier to rule out hardware (i.e., through swapping devices).

Comment: @Ray you may be right. I moved the router 30cm last night and so far I have not seen any issues. So it may be EMI or a dodgy connection. I'm not getting too excited yet - it has been less than 24 hours, but it feels like progress!

Comment: I once had an intermittent network problem and I realised that software doesn't usually (there are exceptions) terminate network connections suddenly due to settings.  It's either a bug in the software or a loose cable, etc.  Software bugs might be experienced by the wider Ubuntu committee...so I'd start with physical connections first...  Out of frustration/anger, I was tempted to buy a proper network cable tester...  Good luck with your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem with a server a couple of months ago, turns out it was a routing problem in my case I got two ether nics, both with a default route, so I deleted one and problem solved, check if it's the same problem in your case.

Comment: Good idea. I recall messing around with network settings when setting up lxc, so I checked it using netstat -rn. This produced:  

    `Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface`
    `0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp2s0`
    `192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp2s0`